# Please how do i Unit Test this method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am having an issue trying to unit Test this method. It pretty seem clear to me first but then i am having difficulty understanding how to effectively inject/mock my array to the bdcontext

```
public class UrlValidation: AbstractValidator<UrlShortenerModel> 
    {
        Uri uriResult;
        private EFDbContext context;
      .....

        public bool notExist(string url)
        {
            //Check if The Url Exist . This is to stop replication of Urls.
            bool exist = context.Urls.Any(x => x.OriginalUrl == url);

            return (exist == false);
        }
   ...

}
```

I want to Test the method notExist. I started below and then stucked on how to mock the value of my context to the class ? Is there any way to represent or mock the context ?. I am using moq for mocking my dummy data but i just don't see the way here. Plus its not a controller class.

```
 public void Should_know_if_Url_Exist_or_Not()
        { 
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            arr.AddRange(new Url[]
            {
                new Url{ UrlId = 0, UrlCode = "TYUR", OriginalUrl="https://fluentvalidation.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 1, UrlCode = "TwUR", OriginalUrl="https://facebook.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 2, UrlCode = "TkUR", OriginalUrl="https://youtube.com/", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now}
            });


            Assert.IsTrue(val.notExist("https://www.youtube.com/"));
            Assert.IsFalse(val.notExist("https://www.facebook.com/"));

        }
```

}

**Update**

When i Changed my test to

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void Should_know_if_Url_Exist_or_Not()
        {
            Mock<IUrlsRepository> mock = new Mock<IUrlsRepository>();
            mock.Setup(u => u.Urls).Returns(new Url[] { 
                new Url{ UrlId = 0, UrlCode = "TYUR", OriginalUrl="https://fluentvalidation.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 1, UrlCode = "TwUR", OriginalUrl="https://facebook.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 2, UrlCode = "TkUR", OriginalUrl="https://youtube.com/", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now}
            }.AsQueryable());



            var validator = new UrlValidation(mock.Object);


            Assert.IsTrue(validator.notExist("https://www.youtuberre.com/"));
            Assert.IsFalse(validator.notExist("https://www.facebook.com/"));

        }
```

and modified my validation class to

```
public IUrlShortenersRepository context;
public UrlValidation(IUrlShortenersRepository repo)
{
  context = repo;
...
```

My test run without an issue however, it fails. But i couldnt run the project again bcos my fluent validation class requires a parameter which i am not sure where to pass . I set my validation class in the model like below

```
 [Validator(typeof(UrlValidation))]
    public class UrlShortenerModel
    {
        //The Model for the Home form. The Url shortener form.
        public string strUrl { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Url> urlList { get; set; }

    }
```

I am not sure where to inject the param.

On a second though , When i check the link provided below here, i get a clear example and therefore modified my test to

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void Should_know_if_Url_Exist_or_Not()
        {
            var arr = new List<Url>
            {
                new Url{ UrlId = 0, UrlCode = "TYUR", OriginalUrl="https://fluentvalidation.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 1, UrlCode = "TwUR", OriginalUrl="https://facebook.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 2, UrlCode = "TkUR", OriginalUrl="https://youtube.com/", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now}
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Url>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Url>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(arr.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Url>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(arr.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Url>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(arr.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Url>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(arr.GetEnumerator()); 

            var fakeContext = new Mock<EFDbContext>();
            fakeContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Urls).Returns(mockSet.Object);

            var validator = new  UrlValidation();
            validator.context = fakeContext.Object;


            Assert.IsTrue(validator.notExist("https://www.youtube.com/"));
            Assert.IsFalse(validator.notExist("https://www.facebook.com/"));

        }
```

I get the 'system.notsupportedexception invalid setup on a non-virtual ' error thrown at   `fakeContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Urls).Returns(mockSet.Object);`. I am suspecting my EFDContext cannot be overriden as explained by the user below. I am not sure how to fix this . My EFDContext class is declared in the context as below.

```
namespace UrlShortener.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Url> Urls { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then changed the properties of EFDContext to virtual here

```
namespace UrlShortener.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Url> Urls { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My test now thrown system.TargetInvocationException 
 WITH A an inner exception `"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."}`. Message `The type initializer for 'Castle.Proxies.DbSet`1Proxy' threw an exception.`  The error was thrown at

`fakeContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Urls).Returns(mockSet.Object);`

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

Comment: How does a `UrlValidation` obtain the context?

Comment: you need to make the context public, and that is fine to expose it because the unit tests is an additional user of this class...

Comment: @jdpPhoneix thats my doubt. My code is working and i m skeptical in making the changes that would accormodate the test . I am required to present the test though .  How do i inject the context ?

Comment: `TargetInvocationException` doesn't give much information - please check the `InnerException` property of it to see the true error.

Comment: @Erik sir please see my ipdate. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you need to use `SetupGet` instead of `Setup` for a property.

Comment: It returns thesame result sir.

Comment: Ah your problem is you're creating `Mock<DbSet>`. Change all instances of `DbSet` to `IDbSet` so that there are no concrete objects interfering with Moq's mechanics. Do that also in your `EFDbContext`.

Comment: If i understand you correctly sir, i should change DbSet in my test to IDbSet and leave the DbSet the way it is in my concrete ?

Comment: Thank you Mr Erik for your time. It works when i changed to IDbSet as you suggested. I had to close and reopen the project though. Also pls any explanation for the IDBset ? Please do write your answ would accept it

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you inject the dbcontext or any other expensive/hard to test dependency into your class under test by using some form of dependency injection (as a constructor argument, with a public setter, using a service locator,...).

That way you can inject a fake implementation for unit testing that is stubbed with fake data and/or fake expectations on method calls.

You can wrap a thin [header interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HeaderInterface.html) around your EFDbContext class to allow for unit testing, or you can just make some properties on the real EFDbContext virtual, as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx).

```
public void Should_know_if_Url_Exist_or_Not()
        { 
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            arr.AddRange(new Url[]
            {
                new Url{ UrlId = 0, UrlCode = "TYUR", OriginalUrl="https://fluentvalidation.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 1, UrlCode = "TwUR", OriginalUrl="https://facebook.com", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now},
                new Url{ UrlId = 2, UrlCode = "TkUR", OriginalUrl="https://youtube.com/", IpAddress="127.0.0.1", PostedDate = DateTime.Now}
            });

            var fakeContext = new Mock<EFDbContext>();
            fakeContext
               .Setup(ctx => ctx.Urls)
               .Returns(arr);
            var validator = new UrlValidation(fakeContext.Object);

            Assert.IsTrue(val.notExist("https://www.youtube.com/"));
            Assert.IsFalse(val.notExist("https://www.facebook.com/"));

        }
```

Comment: As long as you make all the properties and methods in the `EFDbContext` virtual so that, in this instance `moq`, can override the implementations.

Comment: Sir i came across the error you predicted. Please see my update above.